# Rails 3: build places database from google maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps

I have a ruby on rails 3.0 application which will need a database containing the name and address of all the listed places in a certain area indexed by google maps. I don't need to display the map provided by google maps itself, I just need to be able to get the names and addresses of all places in a certain area from google, store this on my server, and then match the address/name a user enters with the place in my database if it exists, or add it if it doesn't. I have some questions about this:

1. Are there any gems out there that would help with this? A quick google search brought up gems which show places graphically on the google map, but this isn't what I need.
2. Approximately how much space will I need to store the names and addresses of, say every place in a city indexed by google maps?

I'd appreciate any feedback on how to go about building the places database using the google maps database as a source and making sure it's quickly accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just implemented an application for Google Places . There were about 4 million records in the Google places Db so the approach i used it you just make a curl call for a google place and store it in Database ,so next time i serve the place from DB.  Don't store all the records in Db as this will make your Db too heavy. also google places allow only 1000 queries per day from a single IP. you also need ranking of the places with Db eg Paris in Canada and Paris in NYC will come together when you will search for paris. Google doesnot provide data according to the ranking . there is a different mechanism for finding ranking of the places

Comment: OK I understand. Could you provide some more details about this? I'm assuming youre using the Google Places API. Did you manually parse the JSON/XML output or did you use a rails gem?

Comment: I didn't mentioned it because it is quite obvious to use google places API. I manually parsed the JSON/XML but simply you can also use [[http://flori.github.com/json/]] gem for parsing. if you are using api then you cannot query more than 1000 times in 24 HRS. So when a user enters any destination, you will make api call to google  auto complete for places , so it will return the name of the place .now when the user selects the destination ,check if the destination exist in the db, if yes ,serve from db else make another call to fetch the data and save in db. Donot fetch data until required

Comment: it will make you app fast bec data is not fetched until required.

Comment: ok. are you manually using REST/JSON for the Google Places Autocomplete API? Because I found a gem link for that, but for some reason I get errors when I run bundle install with that in my Gemfile. Also note if you simply verify your account through your API console and a credit card, you can query 100,000 times in 24 hours for free.

Comment: You are correct about 100,000 limit but i never wanted to give Credit Card Info and i am still confused about your question. You are stuck at Parsing or using Google Places API? because Parsing JSON is much easy. There are many standard JSON parsers like JSON, Crack or you can try this link [[http://blog.brainflint.com/?p=87]]